# Inserting special character in table

Tags: php, joomla

can any one plese help me,

i have one form and when i inserting record in database if some special character in my string then my string breck in database field. like.

INSERT INTO pbdata (id,title,title1) VALUES ('111','statt Josephshöfer kabinett feinherb 2008','Weis');

if i am inserting like this then on database field its only insert record

111   statt Josephsh    Weis

missing character = öfer kabinett feinherb 2008

please help me

thanks,

Comment: An application - like the database or joomla itself - can only deal with the input they can deal with. What you describe is that the characters you use here in strings are not supported. Please contact the manual of the applications you may use (your browser, your webserver, your php, your joomla and your database server) and double check if you use the right settings everywhere to have the characters supported you wish to use. These things are sometimes hard to follow, so you might want to get someone who is assisting you with technical support for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but you should try to enable unicode support or UTF-8 and send the request in this format. It can be an annoying problem requiring configuring the database as well depending on what you want to do.

The problems you run into with this sort of issue are: what format are you displaying the data in (rtf8, unicode?), what format are you using in PHP, and which is the database set to support.

If you google UTF8, mysql, PHP, Joomla you should find more specific examples like:
http://ostraining.com/howtojoomla/how-tos/development/utf-8-in-joomla